# GRUB Menu Not Visible

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub2

I have a bootable external USB drive with Ubuntu 12 LTS, which I move between two PCs. On one machine I see the normal progression from BIOS boot device menu -> GRUB menu -> normal system splash screen. On the other one, though, I go from BIOS menu -> "No video signal" -> splash screen, that is, the monitor turns off while the GRUB menu should be displayed, and then turns back on after GRUB times out.

Can anyone suggest what's going on here, and where I should look for a solution?

Thanks,
Darwin

Comment: Put the monitor that works on the installation that doesnt, and vice versa.  If the same error occurs you have a failing Graphics adapter

Comment: I would, except the one that works is a laptop.

Comment: So test the monitor that isn't working by plugging it into the external VGA port on your laptop.  If the montitor wakes, you have a hardware failure on the machine that isn't displaying grub

Comment: I'll try that later tonight.

Comment: Sorry for the slow turnaround. I just tested it and the monitor works fine on the laptop. That doesn't actually tell me the desktop has an impending hardware failure, though, just that the laptop works as intended. Can anyone suggest a diagnostic tool I can use to test the desktop's video card?

Comment: [How to Identify Which Hardware Component is Failing in Your Computer](http://www.howtogeek.com/174068/how-to-identify-which-hardware-component-is-failing-in-your-computer/) - See the Graphics Card Section, but you may not have a Windows install.

Comment: Finally got around to running PCMark05 on the box this afternoon, and everything passed. I didn't see much point in stress-testing, since the problem only manifests during boot-up. Any other suggestions? (I also realize the problem may actually be related to the label on the front of the box that says "MDG." I'd *like* to get this fixed, but it's really more an annoyance than anything.)

Comment: Hmmm, that only leaves a bad resolution setting.  [See How do I safely change grub2 screen resolution?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/54067/how-do-i-safely-change-grub2-screen-resolution)  Skip Step 1.  Set the resolution in Step 2 to 640x480, then `update-grub` your preferred way.  If 640x480 works go up to the next known resolution, i.e. 1024x768.  Keep increasing til the screen goes black then go one step backwards. Note that if 640x480 goes black, your graphics card is failing to boot in real-mode a.k.a plain VESA

Comment: That was it. Do you want to write it up as an answer or shall I?

Comment: I'll do it I need the reputation :) So do you, but writing your own answer doesn't score anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

The OP is having resolution problems.  The issue here for me (according to comments) was that as a blank slate, I have to determine if the problem exists in the hardware or software.

### Solution

After the OP ruled out hardware problems, it was easy to detemine the issue was with software, in this case GRUB2.  Using the following answer:

[How do I safely change grub2 screen resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54067/how-do-i-safely-change-grub2-screen-resolution)

I advised the OP to skip Step 1, due to the fact that we cannot see the GRUB2 Console, therefore, we must manually setup a repetitive process to manually determine the highest supported resolution:

1. Start at the lowest supported resolution.  On most newer Graphics Hardware the lowest resolution is 640x480.
2. Set the following variable in `/etc/default/grub` using your preferred text editor. `GRUB_GFXMODE`
3. Run `update-grub`.  Please note that the command may be different if your distribution is not Ubuntu based.
4. Reboot
5. Your GRUB2 menu should now be seen in 640x480
6. Repeat steps 1 - 4, increasing the resolution from 640x480 to the point where the screen goes black. Use the well known resolutions such as 1024x768, 1280x1024, etc.  You may also refer to this table: [Screen Resolution Statistics](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/dev/screen-resolution-statistics.htm), starting at the lowest resolution in the 4:3 category, and manually working towards 5:4 then 8:5 and finally 16:9.
7. Once Steps 1 - 4 turns black again, you've reached an unsupported resolution.
8. Repeat Steps 1 - 4 one more time, backing up one resolution.

You may want to add a comment to your grub config file so that this never happens again.  To verify that you're running the maximum supported resolution you can now use the `vbeinfo` command, since you can now use the GRUB2 command prompt.