# Grub menu not visible on TV (but working)

Tags: grub, display, hdmi

My question is similar to this one:
[GRUB Menu Not Visible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241577/grub-menu-not-visible)

To summarize, GRUB seems to be working in so far that it times-out after the expected 10s I set, and starts the expected default OS, but I can't see it, the screen remains black. So I can't start my other OS unless I first start my primary one and use the `sudo grub-reboot 1` command (0 is the primary OS, 1 is the second one)

I tried changing GRUB's resolution, I tested a variety of them, but that yielded no success.

My monitor is a TCL 50C805 TV, connected to my computer (Intel NUC) via a HDMI port.

I'm looking for suggestions for other things I could try, or for a way to find the correct GRUB display parameters from my monitor's specifications.

Comment: Does your NUC have a setting in UEFI on video default video output. Grub uses default where install has its own drivers. My workaround when I had a similar issue, once was just hit down arrow, it worked even though I could not see it. You may need two as recovery mode would probably be one down. I had added a spacer line in 40_custom and made default be spacer line which greatly confused grub.

Comment: I found a setting in the bios that seems somewhat relevant: Devices > Video > IGD Primary Video Port. (display interface used for environments without a graphics driver)
I switched it from Auto to HDMI. But it didn't work.